# Blazor - how to get button innerText

Tags: blazor

<button type="submit" class="bu2ncon10" @onclick="@(()=>{StringClicked = button.innerText;})">

Comment: where do you want to access the button text in JS or in C#?

Comment: C#, will you show also JS please.

Comment: Here is the script how to pass it to C# string?                                                        
     <script>
    document.onclick = function (element) {
        var target = event.srcElement;
    };
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You're the one that sets the text of this button, so you already have it, there's no need to get it